# LOAD ERROR cannot load such file -- task.rb while running .rb file in rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rake-task

I have a file task.rb' file in my lib folder inside my Rails application.

```
task.rb

 users_array = []
CSV.foreach("path/to/.csv file") do |row|
users_array << row
end 

In Rakefile
require File.expand_path('../config/application', __FILE__)
require 'rake'

MyAppName::Application.load_tasks
```

When I try to run this task.rb file in rails console I got the following error.

```
LoadError: cannot load such file -- ./task
from /home/ameex/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /home/ameex/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from (irb):4
from /home/ameex/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
```

I referred many questions here. But nothing helps. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 Dir["#{Rails.root}/lib/**/*.rb"].each do |file|
    require file 
 end
```

put this code in config/initializers/some_file_name.rb

this will load all the files in lib folder while the rails app is loading. Then your file(task.rb) will available in entire app.